# ssis Merge Join Transformation left outer join where col is null

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, ssis

just want to ask about Merge Join Transformation left outer where where Supplier.SupplierCode is null join I have 2 data source  I have this sql script to make it SSIS

```
SELECT Supplier.SupplierCode, Supplier.SupplierName, Supplier.Address, af.SupplierId, af.SupplierCode AS Expr4, af.SupplierName AS Expr5, af.Address AS Expr6, af.EffectiveDate, af.ExpirationDate, af.CurrentFlag,
af.Expr1, af.Expr2, af.Expr3
FROM Supplier LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT DimSupplier.SupplierId, DimSupplier.SupplierCode, DimSupplier.SupplierName, DimSupplier.Address, DimSupplier.EffectiveDate, DimSupplier.ExpirationDate, DimSupplier.CurrentFlag,
Supplier.SupplierCode AS Expr1, Supplier.SupplierName AS Expr2, Supplier.Address AS Expr3
FROM DimSupplier LEFT OUTER JOIN
Supplier ON DimSupplier.SupplierCode = Supplier.SupplierCode) AS af ON Supplier.SupplierCode = af.SupplierCode
where Supplier.SupplierCode is null
```

first I take sup script and make it into data OLE DB Source  Command and  use  Merge Join as Transformation left outer to join the to data stream. just want to ask how can I implement where Supplier.SupplierCode is null in ssis and whate is mean

> Specify whether the transformation handles null values as equal to
>   other nulls. NOTE: If null values are not treated as equal values, the
>   transformation handles null values like the SQL Server Database Engine
>   does.

is it same as where Supplier.SupplierCode is null ?
update what I am trying to remove the null value to insert it to my destination table and remove the delicate

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you want Supplier.SupplierCode to be null and you are joining by supplier code, you will never get any rows because null does not equal null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a conditional split as shown in the below example.

[image]

In the conditional split, use `ISNULL(Supplier.SupplierCode).`.

*I have a suggestion, remove the two sorts used, instead sort the OLEDB source data and make issort = TRUE in both the OLEDB sources.*